# Rate of change necessary assumption

Tags: calculus, derivatives, related-rates

This is an exercise that was given to me.

A particle starts at (0,0) and moves along parabola $y=\dfrac{1}{4}x^2$, $x\geq 0$. In which point of the curve the rate of change of $x$ is equal the rate of change of $y$? Suppose $x'(t)>0$ for all $t\geq0$.

Μy question is related to the assumptions of the exercise. It is necessary the assumption $x'(t)>0$ for all $t\geq0$?

Comment: You mean "rate of change", yes?

Comment: Yes. My mistake.

Comment: No. That assumption isn't necessary, as long as the point eventually reaches the location in question. It doesn't matter if it stops or goes backwards.

Comment: ...although anywhere it stops we have $x'=y'=0$. The extra assumption is probably meant to rule out these extraneous solutions.

Comment: So it is sufficient to suppose that $x'(t)\ne0$. Although, when I read the first sentence of the exercise I understand that it never stops.